# merge sort vs insertion sort time complexity

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, logarithms

How do I solve exercise 1.2-2 from

**Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition**, *Author: Thomas H. Cormen*

[image: Excercise 1.2-2]

Would I need to set both sides equal to each other and solve for n?

Comment: Yes. This is probably most easily done via trial and error.

Comment: its not easily solvable just like solving an algebraic equation ? Its been a while since I've taken any math classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, you should prove that for all integers $k>0$, if you have an integer $N>0$ such that $2^{N}>N^{k}$, then, for all $n\geq N$, $2^{n}>n^{k}$ (or, more generally, there is an integer $N$ such that $2^{n}>p\left(n\right)$ for all $n\geq N$ where $p$ is any polynomial). This is a simple induction argument, and should be done in any algorithms course. From there, you set up the problem like so:

You're given that $8n^{2}<64n\lg n$. So, after a bit of algebra (you can do this part), we get it in to the form $2^{n}<n^{8}$. We have to find all $n>0$ such that this holds, and so, once we have found $N$ such that $2^{N}<N^{8}$ and $2^{N+1}\geq\left(N+1\right)^{8}$, we will know that all integers in the interval $1\leq n\leq N$ satisfy the problem. You can easily find $N$ with a calculator.

(*Hint:* $N$ is bigger than 40 but less than 45)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

Solve for n=8*log(n)

*Note: Log base '2'*

By hit and trial one can easily see that '**43.56**' satisfies the above equation.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm 1 : 8n^2
Algorithm 2 : 64n*ln(n)

You can simply  search these two equations in Wolphram Alpha or just run both these formulas for n in Microsoft Excel you will see that Algorithm 2 starts performing better after n = 26.

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8n%5E2%2C+64n*ln%28n%29](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8n%5E2%2C%2064n*ln%28n%29)