# Insertion and merge sort complexity - CLRS 1.2-2

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

My question is related to an already answered question: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613369/merge-sort-vs-insertion-sort-time-complexity) (New here, could not comment on that answer).

Is there a way to solve for $n$ in $2^n = n^k$ without resorting to trial and error or plotting?

Thanks.